# CosmosDB heterogenous document collection - composite indexing

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using a single collection for all my documents and then instantiating them into POCO's using a property of "type".  Things have been going great so far.

Now I need to add multiple sorting abilities.

That doesn't work and it says a I need a composite index.  Fine, I understand.

But how would I create an `Indexing policy` when it wants `paths` that won't exist in some document types or may exist in more than one document type?

Do I really have to create a collection for each document type for this to work?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will simply ignore those items. Also note that while, for composite indexes, you have to specify paths to include along with their sort order. For the regular index it's generally preferable to include all paths (i.e. "/*") and then specify those paths to exclude. This way you don't need to keep updating your index policy when you add new entity types into your collection.

Also, note that the max number of composite index paths per composite index is 8 per container. Also currently queries will only use one path at a time but this will change very soon to use multiple paths at the same time which will have significant performance improvement to queries which use them.

Comment: Huge help.  I changed my repository to allow documents to be placed in their own container, which I know might affect transaction capabilities.  Thanks for the tip of 8.  So the `compositeIndexes` array can handle more than 8 entries in it, but inside a single index there can only be 8 paths.  Do I have that right?  I can't find that in the docs.  Any chance you have link?  Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, correct, it can only support 8 paths per index. But you can have hundreds of indexes. Yes, documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#sql-query-limits Thanks!